# Quiet places in Kalos

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Are there any places in Kalos where the background music is little to none? I'm kind of hoping to record the little cries from Pokémon Amie with as little interference as possible.

Of course, if someone's already ripped these cries and I just suck at Googling, perhaps someone could point me to the right place? :p

Comment: Hmm... Cave of Emptiness/Sea spirit's den comes to mind, no music whatsoever but there are water drop sounds.

Comment: Actually, I believe Zygarde's chamber @ Terminus Cave has absolutely no sound at all if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Aha! Found one!

The "haunted" house just south of that town with the Fairy Gym, is completely silent. Not even the sound of creaking or anything, just silence.

This worked out perfectly for all my recording needs :)